# Logstash twitter config - search only people i follow?

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch, logstash

Does anyone know how i can modify this logstash so that it only watches feeds of those my twitter account follows?

```html
input {
    twitter {
        # add your data
        consumer_key => ""
        consumer_secret => ""
        oauth_token => ""
        oauth_token_secret => ""
        full_tweet => true
        keywords => ["pizza"]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch_http {
        host => "localhost"
        index => "twitter"
        index_type => "tweet"
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading the documentation I would say that it is not possible, maybe create a feature request to support setting the url to call. In your case you would need this: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline

Comment: Did you get this working? It looks like the old twitter river supported specific feeds.